# How can I synchronize three database from different locations?

Tags: sql-server

I have three databases in different locations. One of these databases is central database. I want synchronize central database with other two databases.

For reaching the goal, current implementation and problems are followed:

1. I tried mirroring but central database is unable to read nor write.
2. I wrote an C# desktop application connecting to servers. This application also  reads tables row by row and insert (or update) to central database. However, SQL Server CPU usage was very high.

For current difficulties, following questions need to be solved:

1. How can I synchronize central databases?
2. What is positive or negative consequences if use registered servers and procedures?

Comment: Writing an application is the worst choice you can ever have. Did you check `Sql Server Always On`

Answer (score 1):

[SymmetricDS](https://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview) can be used to replicate remote MSSQL databases into a single central database.

You can either set it up to multi-tenant so that each remote database will load into a dedicated database at the central or add an additional column to your central tables to indicate a location id.

In SymmetricDS transforms can be configured while replicating from the location into central to provide the location id dynamically as part of the replication.  If you need to also replicate from central to the locations a column match router in SymmetricDS would inspect each change row for the location column and send it only to the appropriate target.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not referenced to C#.

In databases we have some mechanism to Synchronize data. 
What type of synchronization you need?

If you want to copy data from one server to another(for example for Dev\Stg environment), you can use Incremental backups and setup some powershell scripts to execute it one time per day.

If you want to have a reserve database for increase availability, you can use mirroring.

One more case, you can use DB-reference and write jobs on SQL, that will sync data.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I searched for this and I found some information about how to synchronize multiple databases in SQL Server. Below I have mentioned a few of them.

1. SQL Server replication
2. Change data capture in SQL Server
3. Using SQL Server profiler you can capture workload and run it your desire database.

Comment: >>>Using SQL Server profiler you can capture workload and run it your desire database<<< No, you cannot. SQL Server Profiler does not capture sp parameters

Answer (score 0):

I work for a company called Redactics (https://www.redactics.com), and we came up with a solution for delta updating multiple databases using a combination of tracking new primary keys and modification timestamps. Since these workflows are pretty fast to run, this can produce the effect of near real-time replication without the technical overhead (and cost) of replication.

I know this thread is a little old now, so I'll stop here rather than laying on the sales talk thick, but if you are still looking for a solution here please contact us, we'd be happy to to discuss this with you!